# Ошибка 13. type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

Есть макрос, работал пару недель исправно. Сегодня выдал ошибку 13 в строке .Cells(lRwStart, lClmn).Value = dDate ' дата  файла'. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что сломалось?

```vba
Sub updateEO()
Dim aData(), aShop(), aRes()
Dim sPath As String, dDate As Date, bFlag As Boolean
Dim i As Long, k As Long
Const sFolder As String = "C:\Manager\ЭО\" '"
Const lRwStart As Long = 12 ' начало диапазона'
With ActiveSheet
    i = 115 ' завершение диапазона'
    If i < 5 Then Exit Sub
    aShop = .Cells(lRwStart, 1).Resize(i - lRwStart + 1, 1).Value
End With

ReDim aRes(1 To UBound(aShop), 1 To 1)
dDate = Date

Do
    sPath = sFolder & "Экономический отчет (" & Format(dDate, "dd.mm.yyyy") & ").xls"
    If Dir(sPath, vbDirectory) <> "" Then bFlag = True: Exit Do  ' файл найден'
    dDate = dDate - 1 ' если не найден, уменьшаем дату для следующего имени файла'
Loop Until dDate = Date - 5 ' просматриваем максимум 5 файлов (5 дат)'

If bFlag = False Then MsgBox "Нет файла-донора", 64, "ОШИБКА": GoTo err_

With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .DisplayAlerts = False: End With

With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sPath) ' открыть книгу'
    With Worksheets(Format(dDate, "dd.mm.yyyy")) ' если есть сомнения в наличии листа, нужна доп. проверка'
        i = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row - 1
        aData = .Range("B1:K" & i).Value
    End With

    .Close
End With

For k = 1 To UBound(aShop)
    For i = 1 To UBound(aData)
        If aShop(k, 1) = aData(i, 1) Then aRes(k, 1) = aData(i, 10) ' записываем найденное'
    Next i
Next k

With ActiveSheet
    lClmn = Application.Match("за день", Range("A11:ZZ11"), 0)
    .Cells(lRwStart, lClmn).Value = dDate ' дата  файла'
    .Cells(lRwStart, lClmn).Resize(UBound(aRes), 1).Value = aRes ' выгрузка на лист'
End With
err_:
With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .DisplayAlerts = True: End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Избавляйтесь от ActiveSheet, заменяйте на объект со ссылкой на конкретный лист.

Comment: проблема в том, что листы меняются переодически и макрос хотелось бы применять каждый раз на новом, получается от ActiveSheet не избавится (ну можно каждый раз конкретный лист в макрос прописывать, но это как-то сложно)

Comment: *листы меняются переодически и макрос хотелось бы применять каждый раз на новом, получается от ActiveSheet не избавится* Ну ерунды-то не говори... пиши первым оператором `Set sht=ActiveSheet` - и дальше ссылайся только на sht. Если по какой-то причине фокус с листа уползёт - на переменную это не повлияет. Если сильно боишься - ну можешь сделать `set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)`...

Comment: Плохо дружу с вба, буду пробовать, спасибо. А то, что я добавил кнопку Актив Х и привязал 3 схожих макроса к кнопке не может влиять? Код кнопки: Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call updateEO
Call updateEO2
Call updateEO3
End Sub

Comment: я добавил Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name) в начало макроса и ActiveSheet в 2х местах заменил на With sht. Ошибка осталась.

Comment: Это мой код. Если помните, `With ActiveSheet` - для универсальности, чтобы можно было без особых знаний заменить на обрабатываемый лист.  `Set sht = Sheets(...)` - объект в переменную, `With Sheets(...)` - практически то же самое, но без выделенной переменной (на лету), после `End With` ссылка на объект уничтожается. Посмотрите (при ошибке) чему равны переменные `dDate`. `lClmn` (кстати, эта куда пропала из объявленных переменных?). Возможно, нет текста "за день" в строке 11 обрабатываемого листа

Comment: lClmn пропала потому что её я забыл вписать в код, часть про поиск столбца добавил, переменную нет. Добавил. Действительно из 11 строки убрали текст "за день"... Если lClmn = Application.Match("за день", Range("A12:ZZ12") изменить на lClmn = Application.Match("за день", Range("A5:ZZ20"), для подстраховки так сказать, ничего страшного?

Comment: попробовал вышеуказанное, не работает) ок, пусть будет A12:ZZ12, буду знать. Спасибо.